# Close all button for W3School accordion (html, css, js only)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project that requires an accordion, which I found on W3School and it works well.

I am trying to add a close all button using Javascript but with no success.

I am pretty noob with Javascript, from what I understand in the original code, whenever we click on "accordion" it gets the class "active", then the "panel" class that is directly under where we clicked will either close or open to a certain height.

So for the close all button, I tried to create a button and whenever we click on it all the text class would close the same way than the previous function.

Not sure why it doesn't work, so I changed the code, when we click the close all button, the text become red (just to test), and it works fine.

When I try with maxHeight = null; I don't get any error message.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

( see code below )

https://jsfiddle.net/16qpjv5y/3/

HTML + JAVASCRIPT

```
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="closeall" onclick="collapseall()">Close All</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

function collapseall() { //problematic part
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    var b;
    for (b = 0; b < x.length; b++) {
         x[b].style.maxHeight = null;
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.closeall {
    float: right;
    margin: 1% 2% 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying the maxheight change to `.text` and it should be `.panel`. But then you need to remove the `.active` class from the buttons, too.

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.closeall {
    float: right;
    margin: 1% 2% 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="closeall" onclick="collapseall()">Close All</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

function collapseall() {  //problematic part
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    var b;
    for (b = 0; b < x.length; b++) {
        x[b].style.maxHeight = null;
        x[b].previousElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: oh thats why! I tested your way and it works too. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this for example like this:

```
function collapseall() {  //problematic part
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var b;
    for (b = 0; b < x.length; b++) {
    x[b].classList.remove("active");
    var panel = x[b].nextElementSibling;
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
}
```

The problem is that you are finding all elements with class `.text` instead of `.panel` which has transitions and other proper CSS set.

Comment: oh thats why, I didnt pay attention to CSS! I test your way and it works. Thanks alot.